# Why can the lower 2 bits in the process's virtual address space be used as flags in Linux

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, heap-memory

I am leanring the source code for radix tree in the Linux kernel, and I am very curious about a function of the radix tree (as shown below), which uses the lower 2 bits of the pointer address of an entry as a flag for the internal node. Besides, I also found that the `mmap` module uses the lower 2 bit to identify the anonymous pages.

My question is, in the Linux process address space, the lower 2 bits are never used? In other words, the `kmalloc` function always allocates a pointer address whose lower 2 bits are 0. And is this feature available in user space?

```c
//#define RADIX_TREE_ENTRY_MASK     3UL
//#define RADIX_TREE_INTERNAL_NODE  1UL
static inline bool radix_tree_is_internal_node(void *ptr)
{
    return ((unsigned long)ptr & RADIX_TREE_ENTRY_MASK) ==
           RADIX_TREE_INTERNAL_NODE;
}
```

Comment: "the kmalloc function always allocates a pointer address whose lower 2 bits are 0."  Yes, or in other words, an address that's aligned to a 4-byte boundary.  Sure, you can get alignment in userspace.  Ordinary `malloc` will provide some amount of alignment by default, typically 16 bytes, and if you want more there is `posix_memalign`.

Comment: Of course, you have to actually zero out those bits before attempting to dereference the pointer, or the machine will access the wrong address.